# JSON parse log entry

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I'm using [OMS-Docker](https://github.com/microsoft/OMS-docker) to monitor the stdout and stderr of a docker container I'm running. I formatted the output to be in JSON output so I could parse it and search logs more easily.
When viewing the logentry it looks like this:

```
2020-07-02T23:34:24.130271534Z {\"level\":\"debug\",\"ts\":1593732864.1298144,\"caller\":\"services...
```

Apparently OMS adds a timestamp, therefore I cannot parse the json directly.

```
ContainerLog
| extend replaced = replace(@"[\\]", @"", LogEntry)
| extend parsedLogs = parse_json(extract("{(.*):[^{}]*}", 0, replaced))
| where parsedLogs.level == "debug"
| sort by TimeGenerated desc
```

first I need to delete all backslashes and then extract the regex with a json to be able to parse it. I think this isn't a really elegant solution, is there a way to send the logs, the way they are output by the docker container?

Answer (score 0):

I developed a command line tool to view json log (see https://github.com/qiangyt/jog). It is just like 'tail -f log-file' but it's for json log.

It supports OMS-docker by removing backslashes from escaped double quotes.

I'm not quite sure what output you're expecting. Currently, this tool outputs flat regular lines. Do you want output JSON with backslashes removed? If so, let me know, it's easy for me to update it to support that.